# Loading external SWF in Actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-2, flash

I am creating an animation within Flash CS4 in Actionscript 2.0 / Flash Player 7

At the moment I have a handler (Movie Clip) called `myHolder` that is used to play other swf files within one main swf file, when called by a button

Within a button that load the swf into the main timeline - For Example

```
on (press)
{
    loadMovie("BulletTrainDRAFT.swf", myHolder);
}
```

This works fine with bring other swf files into the main swf file timeline, but when I bring a swf file that has video controls for a video within it, they do not respond within the handler when played, but they do work when that swf file is played within its own external flash player window **(The video is within a (Movie Clip) on its own timeline within its design fla)**

Video buttons - ActionScript 2.0

```
btnStop.onPress = function(){

    _root.vid.stop();

}
btnPlay.onPress = function(){

    _root.vid.play();

}

btn_fastforward.onPress = function(){

    _root.vid.nextFrame();

}

btn_Rewind.onPress = function(){

    _root.vid.prevFrame();

}
```

I tried ActionScript 3.0 code as well

```
Pausebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseHandler);
Stopbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopHandler);
Playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playHandler);

function stopHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
// Pause the stream and move the playhead back to
// the beginning of the stream.
video.gotoAndStop(1);
}
function playHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
// Pause the stream and move the playhead back to
// the beginning of the stream.
video.play();
}
function pauseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
// Pause the stream and move the playhead back to
// the beginning of the stream.
video.stop();
}
```

Problem I have I think, is that a movie the external swf loads on the existing timeline as a child and doesn't unload the timeline resulting the actionscript not functional, but I can't fix this.

Comment: What is _root.video ? If the SWF is loaded into myHolder and you want to control it main timeline, for exemple to stop it, then you need to use myHolder.stop(). There is a loading time so you should take a look at the MovieClipLoader class (in AS2).

Comment: This problem has been solved now, but thank you again for your suggestion and help ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed by adding

```
this._lockroot=true
```

to the video main fla timeline, after some help on the adobe forums ^_^

Thank you again everyone for your help